# TortoiseSVN - "is locked in another working copy" error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Every time I try to commit any file in Tortoise SVN the following message shows up: "... is locked in another working copy".
I`ve already done the cleanup, but the problem remains. Someone knows what should I do`to fix it?

Appreciate any help[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px4Ud.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SVN frequently says file is locked by me in another working copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862134/svn-frequently-says-file-is-locked-by-me-in-another-working-copy)

Answer (score 2):

Options you can try:

1 - Try selecting the break lock option during clean up. [Select the break lock option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fHol.jpg)

2 - Try to steal the lock. Look at the image. [Try to steal the lock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQWV9.jpg) This will show you the lock status and should allow you to steal the lock and commit.

3 - You can "break the lock" at the server. I am not sure how to do this using the GUI but following is the command:

```
svn unlock --force http://svn.example.com/repos/project/trunk/somefile.txt
'somefile.txt' unlocked.
```

Comment: the problem remains :/

Comment: What do you mean saying "steal the lock"?

Comment: What is happening is the file is locked in another working copy. A working copy that might not be owned by you... In process anybody can take the lock...So by stealing the lock you take the lock in your current working copy and then you can try breaking the lock and cleaning it up... It should definitely work...

Comment: Problem solved. I clicked in TortoiseSVN -> Get lock... Then I selected the files with the option Steal the lock. After that, I clicked in Realeased the lock... And all the users were finally able to edit.

Comment: The command `svn unlock --force http://...` works for me. 亲测有效。